# How work these threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a small code just for test

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def A
 puts "A"
 sleep 2
end

def B
  puts "B"
  sleep 2
end

[ 
  Thread.new(loop{A()}),
  Thread.new(loop{B()}) 
].each do |thr|
    thr.join
  end
```

and it didn't works as I wish.
I hoped that I'll get

```
A
B
A
B
```

and so on, but I got just

```
A
A
A
A
```

It means that only 1st thread was started.
Does it means that ruby waits when 1st Thread will be closed to start the 2nd one ?
How I could run Thread as thread, I'd like to have threads in my app which will be in parallel make their work and main application thread will be its own job.

What could you advise me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running the loop in the threads, the code is running the loop inside the main thread; which make the threads not to start because of the infinite loop.

Replace following lines (parentheses):

```
[
  Thread.new(loop{A()}),
  Thread.new(loop{B()}) 
]
```

with (braces):

```
[
  Thread.new{loop{A()}},
  Thread.new{loop{B()}} 
]
```

to pass the block instead of the return value of the (infinite) loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to Thread ctor does not do what you expect. You are passing the result of the loop block to the Thread constructor. This way, the loop has to end before the Thread could start. But since your loop is never ending, you only see the `A()` method output which is being executed in the current thread.

Try calling it this way:

```
[
 Thread.new{loop{A()}},
 Thread.new{loop{B()}}
]
```